# Can't get ID to insert into database from HTML Form (using PHP)

Tags: php, html, mysql

Right now I am trying to create a edit form for my forum, and while I CAN get it to edit, it does not insert an ID to the database (rendering it 0 and thus faulty), the ID field have Auto increment and I've double checked it is the primary field. Tried looking over it many times, but there's got to be something I am missing.

The DB connection:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();

$host = 'HOSTNAME';
$dbusername = 'USERNAME';
$dbpassword = 'PASSWORD';

$anslutning = mysqli_connect($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword) or die("<b>Could not connect to database server</b>");

$anslutning->select_db('DATABASE NAME') or die("<b>Could not connect to the specified database</b>");

?>
```

The form where you edit the post (`$edit` in this scenario is the ID it grabs when clicking "edit" on a post), as well as where I try to update the database field.

```
<?php

            if(isset($_GET['edit'])) {
            // If click on "edit"


                $edit = $_GET['edit'];
                // The post-editing ID

                $getEditData = $anslutning->prepare("SELECT postId, title, content FROM tblPosts WHERE postid='$edit' LIMIT 1");
                $getEditData->bind_result($postId, $title, $content);
                $getEditData->store_result();
                $getEditData->execute();

                while($row = $getEditData->fetch()) {

                    echo '
                    <div class="editForm">
                        <form action="index.php" method="POST">
                            <input type="hidden" name="author" value="'.$_SESSION['loggedIn'].'">
                            <input type="hidden" name="edit" value="'.$edit.'">
                            Title: <input type="text" name="new_title" value="'.$title.'"> <br /> <br />
                            Content: <textarea name="new_content"> '.$content.' </textarea> <br /> <br />

                            <input type="submit" name="editPost">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    ';
            }
            }

            // Issue(s): Editing a post does not send postId/edit(id) to database

            if(isset($_POST['editPost'])) {

                $edit = $_GET['edit'];
                $author = $_POST['author'];
                $new_title = $_POST['new_title'];
                $new_content = $_POST['new_content'];

                $updatePost = $anslutning->prepare("UPDATE tblPosts SET postId=?, author=?, title=?, content=?");
                $updatePost->bind_param("isss", $edit, $author, $new_title, $new_content);
                $updatePost->execute();
                echo 'Post updated. Redirecting..';
                sleep(1);
                echo '<script> window.location.href = "index.php?forum=1" </script>';
            }

        ?>
```

Comment: just a note: NEVER EVER use $_GET, $_POST variables directly. Always filter them for sql injection attempts. You can find tons of documentation and samples on stackoverflow and google on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$edit = $_GET['edit'];
```

to

```
$edit = $_POST['edit'];
```

Comment: That, along with manually re-setting a ID seemed to do the trick. No idea why i didn't think of that. Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, was just waiting for the timer to allow me to mark it as answer! :)